# Scanning with scanimage from php from a linux host

Tags: php, linux, image, scanning

Here's what the situation is: I am trying to use PHP to call `scanimage` on a Linux host, then save the resulting file to a web directory for future use.

The below code produces no errors, but when I check out the /tmp directory, file.pnm is blank, and the scanner never starts.

```
<?php
require('/var/www/olin/includes/functions.php');
$con = connect_db();

//setup the POST variables
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $license_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['license_no']);
    $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comments']);
} 


if ($license_no == '') { 
        $license_no = "None on File";
}

if ($fname == '' || $lname == '') { 
        echo '<h1 class="message">Can\'t submit visitor: you are missing information!</h1>'; 
} else {

    //setup the query and prepare it for exection
    $query=     "insert into visitors (fname, lname, license_no, redsheet, comments)" .
        " values (?, ?, ?, 'Allow', ?) on duplicate key update fname = values(fname)," .
        "lname = values(lname), license_no = values(license_no), redsheet = values(redsheet)," .
            "comments = values(comments)";
    $stmnt=     mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

    //bind the statement parameters to variables
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmnt, "ssss", $fname, $lname, $license_no, $comments );

    //execute, then close the statment
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmnt)) {
        echo "Failed to ececute the query: " . mysqli_error($con);
        header('Refresh: 10; url=http://localhost/olin/visitor.php');
    } 
}

// we'll `try` to scan the license  if the checkbox is selected
if (isset($_POST['pic_id'])) { 
    // get the info from the db
    $query = 'select id from visitors where license_no = "'.$license_no.'"';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];

        // set up the path to save the id to (and put path into db for further look    up
        // and display)
        $dir = ( $id % 30 );

        $path = '/var/www/olin/images/licenses/'.$dir.'/'.$id.'-license.png';
        $path = addslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $path));
        $path1 = '/images/licenses/'.$dir.'/'.$id.'-license.png';

        // start the scan, and save image
        $command = '/home/jmd9qs/bin/scan.sh "'.$path.'"';

        $update = 'update visitors set id_pic = "'.$path1.'" where id="'.$id.'"';
        mysqli_query($con, $update) or die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        exec($command);
        header('Location: http://localhost/olin/visitor.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Can anybody provide any hints?

UPDATE:

I have the server running the command now (I know it's failing because of the Apache2 error log).

Here's the error I get:
    `scanimage: open of device brother3:bus2;dev1 failed: Invalid argument`

I've tried adding the www-data user to the `scanner` and `lp` groups, but it seems to have no effect... The `scanimage` command I'm using works under my normal user and as root, so I'm now positive the command I'm using should work. I am still at a loss...

UPDATE (again):

I've fixed some errors in my code... now the server *will* scan and successfully save images! However, it only works once and then for some odd reason I have to run the `scan.sh` (which I put the `scanimage` command into) through my shell for it to run again... otherwise I get the same error message!

Very weird, I have NO clue why, suggestions wanted!

Comment: I think I have this working now... I had to change the udev rules for libsane... I get a "invalid rule" error message on bootup, but I haven't had any issues after changing it!

Comment: Here's the link for where I found the new udev rules: (http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html#u9.10)